# extract the subset of a pandas multi index data frame

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

```
>new_dat=dat_corr.merge(dat_class,on="Asset",how="right").set_index(['Country','‌​Class','Asset'])
>new_dat.shape
(89, 89) 
>temp1='UNITEDSTATES' 
>temp2='Equity'
>new_dat.loc[ (new_dat.index.get_level_values('Country').isin([temp1]) & new_dat.index.get_level_values('Class').isin([temp2]))]'
>new_dat.columns=new_dat.index
```

The last line gives me [3 rows x 89 columns]. My 89 columns is a mix of Equity/FX/FI/Commodities. If i want only USA Equities vs all other equity and not the enitre 89 columns how do i do it? 
I have also added multi index for the columns. The question is now that i have multi index along both rows and columns how do i use that for filtering
The below is a small subset of the data:

Country                       UNITEDSTATES                        CANADA  \
Class                               Equity                        Equity
Asset                             DJ1Index  SP1Index  ND1Index  PT1Index
Country      Class  Asset
UNITEDSTATES Equity DJ1Index      1.000000  0.958038  0.747192  0.648373
                    SP1Index      0.958038  1.000000  0.825458  0.717545
                    ND1Index      0.747192  0.825458  1.000000  0.612487
CANADA       Equity PT1Index      0.648373  0.717545  0.612487  1.000000
MEXICO       Equity IS1Index      0.622570  0.664499  0.565702  0.575618

Country                         MEXICO    BRAZIL   GERMANY   BRITAIN  \
Class                           Equity    Equity    Equity    Equity
Asset                         IS1Index  BZ1Index  VG1Index   Z1Index
Country      Class  Asset
UNITEDSTATES Equity DJ1Index  0.622570  0.523704  0.566993  0.520526
                    SP1Index  0.664499  0.565941  0.587933  0.539138
                    ND1Index  0.565702  0.484441  0.458135  0.391391
CANADA       Equity PT1Index  0.575618  0.526663  0.499343  0.493260
MEXICO       Equity IS1Index  1.000000  0.577041  0.502558  0.487487

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your column(s) to the `.loc` method after comma like this:

```
df.loc[(cond1) & (cond2), 'column_name']
```

This will output your `df` filtered by your conditions with only one column `column_name`.

You can have multiple columns if you put them in the list:

```
df.loc[(cond1) & (cond2), ['column_name1', 'column_name2']]
```

You can see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index) for more details.

**EDIT:**

In case your columns are also `MultiIndex` you could use `IndexSlice` for that:

```
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[(cond1) & (cond2), idx[:,'column_name']]
```

Note that `idx[:,'column_name']` should be adjusted to your MultiIndex setup. I.e. you need to have `:` or `column_name`(s) for every level of `MultiIndex`.

You might find useful examples of how to use this in the [`MultiIndex` docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers). Worth noting the warnings on the need to have your `Index` lexsorted and you pandas version should be 0.14.+.

If you would put a reproducible example of the dataframe it would be easier to give a more concrete answer.

Comment: Thank you for the response. However that is not helping me achieve what i wanted. I have updated the question.

Comment: Sorry, this was not clear to me from the question. I have added more information above. Hope this helps.

Comment: >new_dat1=new_dat.loc[
        (new_dat.index.get_level_values('Country').isin([temp1])
        & new_dat.index.get_level_values('Class').isin([temp2]))]
     
     
    >new_dat2=new_dat1.xs(temp3, level='Country', axis=1, drop_level=False)    
    >final_dat=new_dat2.xs(temp4, level='Class', axis=1, drop_level=False)    This was used to filter for multiindex (rows and columns)